# What is a free and easy to use IIS 7 log viewer?

Tags: iis7, free, logging

I have raw IIS 7 logs I'd like to look at. An excel type view where I can sort by columns is fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in a better answer. For now I'm using:

1. [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) to export

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2>logParser "select * from
>   c:\u_ex111203\u_ex111203.log" -o:CSV>>c:\u_ex111203.csv

1. Using Excel ([Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/) will work) to read it.